# Can I replace 820uF 250v with 1000uF 200v capacitor

Tags: capacitor, replacement

I have 820uF 250v  two capacitors in my power supply board. Its not working correctly and giving low voltage in the following form

Expected voltage - Getting voltage
24v to 23.2v
12v to 11.4v
5v to 4.3v

Is it okay to replace both 820uF 250v caps with 1000uF 200v
Actually I searched a lot but there is no exact match is found in the market.
[image]

Comment: Do you think changing caps will not increase the  voltage , then what should be faulty for low voltage ?

Comment: There is probably a good reason they are rated at 250 volts.

Comment: May I know that reason.

Comment: Actually its a power supply of copier which works on 110v ac

Comment: When it comes to production building circuits, voltage choice often comes down to cost, supplier, and current company part numbers. Once the engineer knows his design requirements the final choice may be much larger simply because it's cheaper or less bother to stock a second capacitor voltage.

Comment: Well as I read the reason for low voltage must be a bulgy capacitor but can anyone suggest me to replace it with higher voltage or to test something else in the circuit for low voltage

Comment: However, as @Andyaka, there may also be legitimate reasons to specify a higher voltage than you would expect that have to do with the way the power supply works, or what the load might do.

Comment: The load is a 24v motor which rotates the roolers and the problem is at clutch due to low voltage its not getting on within time and slowdown the feed which results in paper jam

Comment: I uploaded the image of capacitor . Have a look on it

Comment: Can anybody suggest me a solution to get proper and expected voltage.

Comment: suggest me the fault part which I should change to get exact value.

Comment: Use digikey, Mouser or similar. No reason to replace it with anything other than the correct value.

Comment: I know replace with different value is not good but I am not getting exact match here

Comment: It depends on what the capacitor is used for, if its a power filter cap in most cases you can go higher than the value of the cap with no problem. But you can't go lower on the voltage rating.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the line voltage is 110 VAC does not mean that higher DC voltages are not present somewhere.  If the bad cap was 250V, stick with that.

Comment: So I can use 1000uf 250v its okay?

Comment: Are you there ?? Please answer me

Comment: Yes, I can't imagine the higher capacitance being a problem, given that electrolytics don't have high precision anyway.  The only problem you might have is size.

Answer (score 1):

From fixya:
renifer Nov 18, 2013

Yes. The voltage *must* be correct. You can go higher on the uf rating, but not lower. The key is to use quality capacitors.

My thoughts:
**Voltage is critical for safety.**
It mentions that **you can have a higher capacitance but NOT lower**.
Having a higher capacitance will change the filtering characteristics, but I'm not an engineer.

Hope this helped.
Source: http://www.fixya.com/support/t7213566-blow_capacitor_820uf_25v_replace_1000uf